# Safari's "Reader Mode" - Open source solution?

Tags: open-source, web, safari, browser

Safari has a "Reader Mode" which removes everything from a website with an article but the text. Does anyone know of an open source library which provides the same functionality? Or, do you think it would be difficult to implement?

Comment: I found this source code: [PHP - how to get main HTML content like Reader Mode in Firefox][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733275/php-how-to-get-main-html-content-like-reader-mode-in-firefox/17735301#17735301

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Safari's reader mode is [based upon](http://blog.arc90.com/2010/06/07/safari-5-another-step-towards-better-reading-on-the-web/#comment-6630) Arc90's [Readability](https://www.readability.com/addons/)(the original, not current, one), which is [Apache-licensed](http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability/). Here's a [PHP port](http://www.keyvan.net/2010/08/php-readability/) of it. Some more searching will probably turn up various other languages. (You didn't really specify *where* you were asking about implementing.)

Comment: Firefox (which is open source) for Android now has the "Reader mode" implemented: http://mzl.la/VDEIFA You will probably have to dig in through their code to see where it is located. And if you do find it, kindly link it back here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm aware of the licencing issue about my post might raise here, but it's Apple and their policies are philosophically contestable. So, for the common good & research :

Safari JS reader source: https://github.com/amumu/safari-reader-js

How to get the latest version from Safari is explained in the README.

If you really want an open source Version, user the other posts, they're all good.

Cheers.

Comment: that URL does not work anymore -- "Repository unavailable due to DMCA takedown." Fortunately, googling for "safari-reader-js" does yield a few results...

Comment: I know. Can't do much about it... exept: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/03/18/safari-reader-source-code or https://github.com/amumu/safari-reader-js

Comment: those are great! could you edit your answer and add those links?

Comment: Mozilla open-sourced their version they use in Firefox https://github.com/mozilla/readability

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fairly popular JavaScript version based on arc90's readability project as well.

https://github.com/luin/readability

Answer (score 1):

Firefox for Android contains a file called Readability.js which says:

- This code is heavily based on Arc90's readability.js (1.7.1) script
- available at: http://code.google.com/p/arc90labs-readability