# How to use Safari's Reading Mode on webView - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

He guys. I want the website to open in reading mode. I want it to open without unnecessary ads and buttons. How can I do that on webView. Sorry for my very bad English. Thanks.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864883/safaris-reader-mode-open-source-solution

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE FOR SWIFT 4, iOS 11**

The `SFSafariViewController` init function that takes an `entersReaderIfAvailable` parameter has been replaced by one that takes an `SFSafariViewController.Configuration` property. To get the old behaviour you can replace the code used in answers above by this:

```
let urlString = "http://www.google.com"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This will do the trick!

Answer (score 3):

First thing you cannot enable "Reader" mode for `WKWebView` or `UIWebView`.
You need to use `SFSafariViewController`

Then you need to set `entersReaderIfAvailable` to true when initializing the instance.

Here an example :

```
    let urlString = "http://google.com"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
    present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```